# on_guild_join data doesn't save on my database

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I test-ran my code using on_guild_join to fetch data from a server it joined and save it in a specific db file, but when I checked that, it was empty, no data was saved in it. I checked that on_guild_join part was working, and gave all intents. Here's the code:

```
class Bot(Botbase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = False
        # self.cogs_ready = Ready()
        self.guild = None
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
        db.autosave(self.scheduler)
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix=get_prefix,
            owner_ids=OWNER_IDS,
            intents=Intents.all()
        )

    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        print('detected new server\ninitiating setup sequence...')
        db.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO war_guild (GuildID) VALUES (?)', guild.id)
        db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels (ChannelName, ChannelID, ChannelType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
                     ((channel.name, channel.id, 'text') for channel in guild.text_channels))
        db.multiexec('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO channels (ChannelName, ChannelID, ChannelType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', 
                     ((channel.name, channel.id, 'voice') for channel in guild.voice_channels))
        print(' updating guild and channel info to a database...')
```

class for command 'execute', 'multiexec':

```
from os.path import isfile
from sqlite3 import connect

DB_PATH = "./data/db/database.db"
BUILD_PATH = "./data/db/build.sql"

cxn = connect(DB_PATH, check_same_thread=False)
cur = cxn.cursor()

def execute(command, *values):
    cur.execute(command, tuple(values))

def multiexec(command, valueset):
    cur.executemany(command, valueset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sqlite3 you need to call `commit()` to save your changes to the database or they will not be visible from other database connections, and hence, lost.

In your case you will need to add `cxn.commit()`. I would suggest to also close the database connection when you are done with it, for that use `cxn.close()`.

#### References:

- [connection.commit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=commit#sqlite3.Connection.commit)
- [connection.close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=close#sqlite3.Connection.close)